# Creating a new Column in Python Pandas while handling NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
year month day
1990 05    23
nan  nan   nan
1991 06    24
1992 07    nan
1993 08    26
nan  nan   nan
```

I need to add a column called `birthday` with the values as the combined value only when all three columns have values

```
birthday
1990-05-23
nan
1991-06-24
nan
1993-08-26
nan
```

I'm creating the column `birthday` as

```
en["birthday"] = en["year"].astype(int).astype(str) + '-' + en["month"].astype(int).astype(str) + '-' + en["day"].astype(int).astype(str)
```

I'm running into a `Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

What is the best way to handle this ?
Here, I haven't implemented a check to see if all of them have values either

The dataframe has other columns as well, so would prefer to avoid any global operations that could affect other columns

Using a `fillna` does help, but I would prefer the empty values as `nan`

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe is well named, just pass to `to_datetime`

```
df['bday']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])

df
Out[32]: 
     year  month   day       bday
0  1990.0    5.0  23.0 1990-05-23
1     NaN    NaN   NaN        NaT
2  1991.0    6.0  24.0 1991-06-24
3  1992.0    7.0   NaN        NaT
4  1993.0    8.0  26.0 1993-08-26
5     NaN    NaN   NaN        NaT
```

From wwnde

```
df['x']=np.where(df.notna().all(1),df.astype(str).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1), np.nan)
```

Comment: I also got a `NaT` for index 3.

Comment: @wwnde pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']]) I think if one column is nan, it will return NaN ~ :-)

Comment: @wwnde ah ~ :-) happy coding ~

Comment: @AChampion index 3 should return NaN ~ , I just paste the wrong output before ~

Comment: @BEN_YO does this help? `df['x']=np.where(df.notna().all(1),df.astype(str).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1), np.nan)`